# How to set the RowStyle of a GridView row depending on a property of the Object that the row is being bound to

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I'm currently using a GridView and I want to set the CssClass for the Row depending on a property of the object that the row is being bound to.

I tried the following but it does not work (see comments):

```
<asp:GridView id="searchResultsGrid" runat="server" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="20" AutoGenerateColumns="false">

<!-- The following line doesn't work because apparently "Code blocks 
aren't allowed in this context: -->
  <RowStyle CssClass="<%#IIF(DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"NeedsAttention","red","") %>

  <Columns>
<!--............-->
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

Now I could simply handle the GridView's RowDataBound event and change the css class of the row there...but I'm trying to keep a clear separation between the UI and the page/business logic layers.

I have no idea how to accomplish this and I'm looking forward to hearing any suggestions.

Thanks,

-Frinny

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot do this in declarative markup.

Nearly all of `GridView`'s declarative properties (including [`GridView.RowStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowstyle.aspx)) are grid-level settings rather than row-level. Apart from  [`TemplateFields`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) , they are not bound data containers, so they don't have access to the data in their rows.

If you want to keep this logic in the .aspx template, your only real option is to use template fields and manipulate their contents:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <span class="<%# ((string)Eval("property3")) == "NeedsAttention" ? "red" : string.Empty %>">
            <%# Eval("property1") %>
        </span>
    </ItemTemplate>                        
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Depending on what you want to do, this may be awkward - you don't have access to the containing `<td>` (or `<tr>` for that matter) and you'll have to repeat the formatting for each cell.

The `GridView` class goes to a lot of lengths to hide the details of HTML and styling from you. After all you *could* create a `GridView` [control adapter](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/12/21/asp-net-2-0-control-adapter-architecture.aspx) that wouldn't even render as HTML tables. (Unlikely though that may be.)

So even though you're trying to avoid it, you're probably best off dealing with this in a `OnRowDataBound` handler - or use a `Repeater` (if that's appropriate).

Comment: Yeah I thought about this too but I wasn't to happy with the fact that I would have to do this for every TemplateField and BoundField in the row. It is going to be awkward. Maybe I'll just bite the bullet and handle the OnRowBound event. So much for keeping my layers separate.

Comment: Thanks Jeff. As disappointing as this answer is, at least  you have confirmed that it's impossible to do this.

Comment: You bet - and I'm sorry to bring the bad news. The GridView is what it is, and has fathered many disappointments; I try to avoid it when I can. When its advantages (such as they are) are irresistable, I just bite the bullet too.

Answer (score 3):

I know it has been almost a year, but if anyone else is trying this, try to subclass the GridView.

```
public class GridViewCSSRowBindable : GridView
{
  public string DataFieldRowCSSClass { get; set; }
  protected override void OnRowDataBound(GridViewRowEventArgs e)
  {
    base.OnRowDataBound(e);
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(DataFieldRowCSSClass))
    {
      //This will throw an exception if the property does not exist on the data item:
      string cssClassString = DataBinder.Eval(e.Row.DataItem, DataFieldRowCSSClass) as string;
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(cssClassString))
      {
        string sep = string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Row.CssClass) ? string.Empty : " ";
        e.Row.CssClass += sep + cssClassString;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And then in your Page:

```
<custom:GridViewCSSRowBindable ID="gvExample" runat="server" DataFieldRowCSSClass="RowCSS">
</custom:GridViewCSSRowBindable>
```

The objects being bound to this example GridView should have a public string RowCSS property.

If you haven't used inherited controls before, you might have to look up how to set that up in your project.

Comment: Because the GridView.RowDataBound is a public event, you can do something simular to this in an event handler.  Using an event handler might be useful if you can't subclass the GridView for some reason.

Comment: I don't even remember posting this question! But, the point was that I didn't want to have code behind controlling style. I wanted to keep my UI stuff in the ASP code, thus avoid using the OnRowDataBound event. So, while your solution will work, I was looking for an alternative way to do this (without using code behind). Thanks for your response though. This will be helpful for those people who were unaware of OnRowBound event.

Comment: @Frinavale you can put Event handlers in a `<script runat="server">` block in the aspx/ascx

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (TableCell gvc in gvRowPhistry.Cells)
{
    gvc.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
}
```

Comment: A little more explanation might help out the fellow programmers to understand how the code works.